# What python library is PIP using to display the cool color status?

Tags: python, pip, colors

I've been trying to use the same color schemas that PIP uses.
Do you have any example of the library that they use?
Would be great if you can share or at least provide any suggestions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPxNZ.png)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

`pip` uses [`rich`](https://pypi.org/project/rich/) vendored at https://github.com/pypa/pip/tree/main/src/pip/_vendor/rich. See the source code at https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/main/src/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py.

Answer (score 0):

These two work great for me:

- https://pypi.org/project/colorama/
- https://pypi.org/project/loguru/

Have fun!